# Compress Table split across rows, creation of wide data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dummy data

```
ID part 1    ID part 2     Year       Value
312          214           2013/14    123
312          214           2014/15    245
312          214           2015/16    126
442          346           2013/14    142
442          346           2014/15    975
442          346           2015/16    245
```

I'm trying to combine it so as to have wide data instead. Using the spread function, `spread(data, Year, Value)` gets me a table similar to the below (ignoring row order).

```
ID part1     ID part2    2013/14         2014/15         2015/16
    312           214        123             NA               NA 
    442           346        142             NA               NA 
    312           214         NA            245               NA
    312           214         NA             NA              126
    442           346         NA             NA              245
    442           346         NA            975               NA
```

The desired output would group them all based on their IDs as per the below.

```
ID part1     ID part2    2013/14         2014/15         2015/16
    312           214        123            245              126 
    442           346        142            975              245
```

Note that it has collected terms based on their two part IDs.

Essentially I'm after the exact opposite of the `gather` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) verbs to group and spread your data to wide format.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "
  ID1 ID2 Year    Value
  312 214 2013/14   123
  312 214 2014/15   245
  312 214 2015/16   126
  442 346 2013/14   142
  442 346 2014/15   975
  442 346 2015/16   245", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  spread(Year, Value) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#     ID1   ID2 `2013/14` `2014/15` `2015/16`
#   <int> <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1   312   214       123       245       126
# 2   442   346       142       975       245
```

Comment: I tried that, it gave me the results in the OP, everything ends up still in multiple rows.

Comment: @DanielV, my solution is reproducible, if you are getting different results I suggest you work from a fresh environment.